# get user's employee id stored in outlook 2013 address book in c#

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

My outlook 2013 address book has a field by the name Employee ID which I  wish to retrieve and display in a message box using c#.Is there a way of doing it?Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide such property or method. But you may find the [ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868616(v=office.15).aspx) property of the ExchangeUser class helpful, it returns a string representing the unique identifier for the ExchangeUser. Here is what MSDN states:

*The ExchangeUser object is derived from the AddressEntry object. It inherits the ID property from the AddressEntry object. The transport provider assigns a permanent, unique string ID when an AddressEntry object is created. These identifiers do not change from one session to another.*

You may also find the [ExchangeUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866281.aspx)'s class memebers helpful. This object provides first-class access to properties applicable to Exchange users such as FirstName, JobTitle, LastName, and OfficeLocation. You can also access other properties specific to the Exchange user that are not exposed in the object model through the PropertyAccessor object. Note that some of the explicit built-in properties are read-write properties. Setting these properties requires the code to be running under an appropriate Exchange administrator account; without sufficient permissions, calling the ExchangeUser.Update method will result in a "permission denied" error.

Try to play with any Extended MAPI property viewer such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy for exploring low-level properties.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the domain login id? Use AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias.